# Ubu20-LTS basically freezes so bad I cant get a functioning terminal to killall chrome -9 - recommend another browser or OS, please

Tags: 20.04, google-chrome

Ubu20-LTS basically freezes so bad I cant get a functioning terminal to killall chrome -9 - recommend another browser or OS, please.

That pretty much says it all AND the freenode channel has been depopulated.

I am totally fed up witn 18.04 and 20.04 doing the same thing. -- on different computers.

<How is the Chrome OS? she asks wryly.>

Ubuntu 6.10 to 11 worked flawlessly. Then came the problems.
This makes my desktop unworkable. What happened to chrome sandbagged tabs? It is a horror (but so convenient when it works).

I have a dell computer, OptiPlex 9020 (05A4) 8G ram.
the only tweaks are to the dock display.

I looked at 4 PAGES of tags and saw nothing related to the system grinding to a (virtual?) halt.

Comment: Try using Firefox, or Brave, or Opera, or many number of other web browsers that are out there.  Chrome is not the greatest browser there is.  It has many issues with it.  Also, having TONS of open tabs in ANY browser will take up memory for each open tab.  Try to limit how many open tabs you have.  Try also running `inxi -t m20` in a terminal window when you have a few tabs open just to see how much memory each one is taking.

Comment: How much memory is used before the system freezes? How much swap do you have?

Comment: dear FedKad, OIK. Perhaps you could reveal the secrets of the guild.  (trying humor, to not look so ignorant.)